# html5 drag & drop problem (dataset)

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

Hi I'm just trying to implement some cool drag and drop stuff to my order form and I have problem with dataset js object. When I bind a function to an ondragstart event and then I try to read event.dataset.value, I get error `TypeError: Result of expression 'event.target.dataset' [undefined] is not an object`. When I log the `event.target` object into console, the dataset object is missing. The data attribute is only comprised in attributes object.
I am using Safari 5.0.5..In google chrome is everything ok.
So is this stuff so bad and incosistently implemented? I thought, at least webkit browser should this handle well, but oposite seems true:)
jQueryUI should fix it, but I wanted to rely on a non-plugin solution..

Comment: provide some code stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to pass a custom data set in the event.

Would it be possible to pass the dataset along separately? I don't know how well other browsers support modifying events at all. I always stay well away from it.

jQuery wraps all events so you can extend them all you want. That doesn't mean it's a very good approach :D